# How to use Lambda to merge two Dictionary with List<string> contain in Dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

I have two dictionaries of type `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`
How could I merge these two dictionaries into one dictionary `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

```
List<string> lstA = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
List<string> lstB = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
var dicA = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> { { "0", lstA } };
var dicB = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> { { "0", lstB } };

var mergeDic = dicA.Concat(dicB)
                   .GroupBy(t => t.Key)
                   .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, d => d.Select(k => k.Value)
                   .ToList());
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you expect the result to be, or why you would want that. This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you explain the problem you're *actually* trying to solve, we could probably suggest a better way.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want the result to be. Please give more details about the requirements. (It may be that you just want `Zip` and then `ToLookup`, but we don't have enough information.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for quickly response. Actually, I have a structure need to fill in data, so I use a dictionary to collect data and value type use List<string>. The different between List<string> is one look like char, another is integer and I need put them together into one List<string>.

Comment: @user3701796 You have not yet answered both  p.s.w.g and jon's questions.

Comment: I just got answer but author has deleted. just change select to selectmany, thanks a lot. if you could put the code again, I will mark it as answer. var mergeDic = dicA.Concat(dicB)
                   .GroupBy(t => t.Key)
                   .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, d => d.SelectMany(k => k.Value)
                   .ToList());

Comment: It looks like you got information on whatever you tried to ask. Please either edit your post so it is clear what you are looking for. I.e. list of ("a", "b", "c") is not really "one that looks like `char`"... and "is not i wanted. Thanks a lot" does not explain what you actually need.

Comment: @JoshTseng It was bit unclear, and I wasn't sure that's what you're asking about, that's why I deleted my answer. Now added it back.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks again, I am new here. It's kind of hard to explain what I wanted. I am trying to merge two List<string> in one and it is a TValue in Dictionary.

Comment: @JoshTseng Welcome, I suggest check [jon's checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to see how to write a good question. Next time express in clear way, thanks.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Got it. I will read it carefully. Very appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `d.Select` to `d.SelectMany`

```
var mergeDic = dicA.Concat(dicB)
                   .GroupBy(t => t.Key)
                   .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, d => d.SelectMany(k => k.Value)
                   .ToList());
```